# Can I load a texture into OpenGL based off of the display density?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Following example code for Android OpenGL programming, I am loading my textures from a raw resource.

eg.,

```
// Create a texture handle
int[] texArray = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texArray, 0);
int textureID = texArray[0];

// Bind the texture and configure parameters
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(etc...);

// Open the image resource as a stream
InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.sometexture);

// Read the stream into a bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

// Load the bitmap into GL
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

bitmap.recycle();
is.close();
```

(My actual code does have error checking etc...)

This is loading a bitmap from a PNG file stored in res/raw/sometexture.png

How do I load an image based on the current display density?  I assume that I would put the images into the various res/drawable-??dpi folders, but then not sure how to load them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I can use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sometexture);
```

and that will load an image from the best available option of the drawable-??dpi folder under /res/.